# How to create dSYM file in XCode 7.0

Tags: xcode, dsym

I am creating dSYM file in XCode 7.0, After archiving my project, I can't find my dSYM file. I referred to lots of sites from stack overflow and followed many instructions but I could not find my dSYM file on any Folder available. Please any one help me.

Please instruct me what are the properties I need to Enable in app Build settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

in xcode -> window -> orgnizer

or
xcode - > product -> Archive

you see Archives window

1 Select any Archives of your app Right click on it Then select show in finder

2 you see aapname.xcarchive file Right click on  it and select show package contents

3 you see dSYMs folder open it and get .dSYM file

:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i tried already But here  am getting only folder name as dSYMs. dSYM file note created. this is only my problem. i think  am missing some option to enable in  app target build settings.

Comment: plz check build settings -> buid options ->Debug Information Format ->  Debug  DWARF with dSYM File  and release  DWARF with dSYM File

Comment: Yes also changed like that.

Comment: Already am faced same issues, fallowed  instruction like you are given. its works fine. But now am facing same issue  in some other project. this project started before 3 years. its started in old xcode i thought its may be the reason. Please if you find help me.

Comment: i am using xcode  Version 7.3 (7D175) update your xcode may be its work for you

Comment: Ok friend. i ll try and tel  you know Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110378/discussion-between-vinayak-and-balkaran-singh).

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you have Debug with **DWARF with dSYM File** enabled

Click on your Project -> Build Settings -> Build Options -> Debug -> DWARF with dSYM File

(see picture below)

[image]

Comment: Why is this a "must"? What benefit is DWARF?

Comment: Where will this dsym file appear? In what directory?

Comment: It will appear in the Products folder of the build. For example: /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<ProjectName>-<...>/Build/Products/<AppName>.app.dSYM